# How to use xpath in Scrapy to scrape a tag without a class or attribute?

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape an html file but the tags do not have any class or id. Is there a way to get an xpath for this without using the regular '//*[class="blah"]/' format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is an option to use just the tags but you need to know the index of a particular one if you want to look at a particular element

ex in the shell

```
response.xpath('//html/body/table[1]')
```

if there are multiple elements with table tag inside the body tag then the [1] will specify the first table tag (xpath starts counting at 1)

Comment: Thank you, I will correct that in my answer